Why there are no separate branches for the latest `polkadot-sdk` releases?
I've noticed there are no release-polkadot-v1.1* branches after the version release-polkadot-v1.14.1, however, the latest release tag is polkadot-v1.16.1. Is there a specific reason for this?

Okay, found this post on the Polkadot forum, explaining the stable releases.
